# TextView Not Displaying After Large Scale Up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

I am working on a project that involves a letter filling up most of the height of the screen. At this point, the height of the letter is supposed to be `428 Pixels`. The height of my screen is well over this, the layout (although a fragment) has ample room to fit the letter, and both the fragment layout and underlying layout are set to `match_parent`. For the `textview` itself, I have it `centerInParent = true` Trust me, I've been doing this a while so I know everything is correct as far as initialization goes, I just can't figure out why the letter wont appear! Oh, I should also note that although the screen can hold that size of a letter, it is tight (talking about approximately 50 pixels above and below), and that the entire activity and layout is set to a `FullScreen` theme, because I assumed it would give it more usable space. Any ideas? Thanks everyone!

**EDIT**: The total number of `pixels` I have in my display height of the monitor is `721`, the letter takes up `428` pixels, after subtracting a few default-sized `buttons`s at the button that leaves me with about `260` pixels of free space. And as I mentioned there is no `actionBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to convert the `textView` using this code: `txt.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` Hope this helps!